# Is it possible to use wild card versions for dotnet global/local tools?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-tool

We use the normal `dotnet-tools.json` for setting up our dotnet local tools for our project but was wondering if there is a way to use wild card versions for the version numbers like you can do within csprojs with package references?

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0-rc.1.*" />
```

I've tried changing the `dotnet-tools.json` to the following:

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-ef": {
      "version": "5.0.0-rc.1.*",
      "commands": [
        "dotnet-ef"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However running `dotnet tool restore` gives the following error

```
Invalid manifest file. Path C:\dev\x\x.api\.config\dotnet-tools.json:
        In package dotnet-ef:
                Version 5.0.0-rc.1.* is invalid.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locating where [error message originated](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/7f3039acb27da27596c1d6a076b7fdd8ea5845fa/src/Cli/dotnet/ToolManifest/ToolManifestEditor.cs#L260) in code, you can see that the version parsing is done by [NugetVersion.TryParse](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/d5e904c463046bf24069a44bf3b7d8cf4969a3fe/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Versioning/NuGetVersionFactory.cs#L36) which only allow semver-strings.
So it isn't possible to add wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

**Update for 2023:**

I just discovered `dotnet tool install` does accept wildcards.
To pin your dotnet-ef version to EF7 for example you can use
`dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef --version 7.*` and it will install the most recent 7.x version. I tested this with both the .Net 7 and 8 sdk's.

Comment: This installs the latest version but it doesn't roll to the latest patch if you do a `dotnet tool restore` as it's pinned to the exact version within the `dotnet-tools.json` still

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, `.config\dotnet-tools.json` really contains definitions of what tool version to actually use, so it can't have wildcards. It is similar in concept to npm [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-lock-json), to find a similar concept in another framework. Unless they decide to introduce a similar semantics for `dotnet-tools.json` in the future, where you can specify wildcards with semantic versioning, and then a lock file is produced separately, then you are left to use other approaches:

- From the command line, you can manually update your package `dotnet tool install` or `dotnet tool update`, specifying a wildcard as suggested by @Joren;
- You can avoid relying in a `dotnet-tools.json` at all, which is now my current approach in a project, and always install latest (or a controlled one with wildcards) version of a tool from the command line, and create `dotnet-tools.json` whenmissing with `dotnet tool install MyTool --create-manifest-if-needed` as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install).